# HTTP notification using Socket.io error

Tags: javascript, node.js

The idea is to send custom notifications using socket.io and node.js server on a VPS with http
and I can connect to the VPS using a webpage, running on my pc
but from my domain I can't use it because it's being blocked.

This Error pops up in browser console:

Blocked active mixed content loading “http://151.236.63.10:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MI4R0M3”

This is my server side node.js server:

```
var app     =     require("express")();
//var mysql   =     require("mysql");
var http    =     require('http').Server(app);
var io      =     require("socket.io")(http);


io.on('connection',function(socket){  
    console.log("A user is connected");
    socket.on('add reserva',function(status){
    io.sockets.emit('update reserva', status);
    });
});


http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Listening on 3000");
});
```

Not sure what im doing wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS on your domain? And does your endpoint on VPS, which you are connecting to, have HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, the domain have HTTPS, but not the VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have mentioned that your domain is using HTTPS, but not your VPS.**

Since your domain is using HTTPS, and now you are trying to connect to your server over HTTP, you are dealing with Mixed Content.

From [Google's Web Fundamentals Docs on Mixed Content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content):

> Mixed content occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS
> connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets,
> scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection. This is called
> mixed content because both HTTP and HTTPS content are being loaded to
> display the same page, and the initial request was secure over HTTPS.

**Solution:**

This can be fixed by replacing all `http://` links on your website with `https://`.

So this means you have to connect to your VPS over HTTPS instead of HTTP. Therefore, you should enable HTTPS/SSL on your server and connect to it over HTTPS.

Or you can disable HTTPS on your domain and use just HTTP.

For more info, refer [MDN Web Docs on fixing a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content).

Comment: I've done some research and i kinda suspected that was the answer, but still you gave me an ideia wich ended up fixing the problem ! Thanks alot!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped.